# how to write a piece of xamarin code without memory (activity) leak

Tags: android, xamarin

I use xamarin to write a very simple app. to start a very simple activity. but, when I use leakCanady, it reports a leak.
the mainActivity is as follows.

namespace SampleApp
{
[Activity(Label = "SampleApp", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
private Button _button;

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);
        _button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
        _button.Click += OnButtonClicked;
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        _button.Click -= OnButtonClicked;
        _button.Dispose();
        base.OnDestroy();
        Dispose();
    }

    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(LeakingActivity));
    }
}
```

}

and the new activity is as follows
public class LeakingActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
//private TextView _textView;

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        //_textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
    }


    
    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Dispose all disposable members
        //_textView.Dispose();

        base.OnDestroy();

    }
    
    
}
```

}

Please help me to solve it. thanks

Comment: you mean that memory leak when you go to other activity? I do one sample to go to other activity, seem there is no problem.

Comment: I start activity b from activity a. and use adb shell dumpsys meminfo package_name to get the count of activities is 2. then I press backpress to close activity b. I hope activity b will totally released( after GC). but adb shows the count remains 2. I found this happens in xamarin. If I wrote code in java with android studio, the count will be 1 so activity b is totally released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't applied `Dispose` in your second activity. As the activity is a native object it doesn't work well with .NET GC as .NET is not aware of its size, it assumes that its size is small. It should be garbage collected eventually even without `Dispose`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It will be very helpful for me